# How would I write this JQuery addClass method in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

So how exactly would i write

```
$('div').addClass('border1');
```

in Vanilla javascript, like what would my add class method look like. So far what I have is,

```
function addClass(x,y) {
    x.className += " " + y;
}
```

but i know this is wrong, as the parameters are off. Im really lost.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: If `x` is a DOM element, it looks right.

Comment: because the format of the $('div').addClass('border1'); so the format of my method id "method (parameter, parameter)" but the method in the calling function is formatted as parameter.method(parameter)

Comment: What are the values of `x` and `y`?

Comment: x should be div and y should be border1

Comment: You don't need to write a function for that, Javascript already does that. You can do `var el = document.getElementById("myId")` and then `el.className = el.classname + ' border1'`

Comment: @seiseises There's no `getElementByTagName`, it's `getelementsByTagName` and then you have to loop over them.

Comment: `->` http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#add_class

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I misspelled it. And I used that just because OP was selecting all divs, I know the usual would be to select by class or id. I fixed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at what jQuery does here.

What is the meaning of `$('div')`?

In jQuery terms it means *"select all 'div' elements in the document"*.
`$('div')` is a jQuery object which represents all `div` elements in the document. But nowhere in this code you specifically target a single DOM element by yourself.

Let's write our own simplified selection object "MySelect":

```
/**
 * `MySelect` object constructor.
 */
function MySelect(selector){
    this.elementList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Now let's use it:

```
var divs = new MySelect('div');
divs.elementList; // all `div` elements in the document.
```

(Note that [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) is a native javascript DOM method)

Now that we have an elements selection object, let's add an `addClass` method to it:

```
/**
 * Add the specified class to all elements selected by this object.
 */
MySelect.prototype.addClass = function(cls){
    var i, e;
    for (i = 0; i < this.elementList.length ; i++){
        e = this.elementList[i];
        e.className += " " + cls;
        // can also use e.classList.add
    }
}
```

And voila:

```
divs.addClass('xyz');
```

This, in a very simplified fashion, is how jQuery works.

For the `$` syntax you can do:

```
function $(selector){
    return new MySelect(selector);
}
```

And use it as usual:

```
$('div').addClass('xyz');
```

Answer (score 4):

[`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) is vanillaJS's way of doing it

```js
var x = document.getElementById('x');
var y = document.getElementById('y');
var z = document.getElementById('z');

y.addEventListener('click',function(){

  x.classList.add('blue');

});

z.addEventListener('click',function(){

  x.classList.toggle('blue');

});
```

```css
#x {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>

<button id="y">add the class</button>
<button id="z">toggle the class</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, so i understand what you're doing but my question is how would i write the addClass method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targetting IE10+, you can use

```
 var el = document.getElementById("someId");
 el.classList.add(className);
```

For all browsers :

```
if (el.classList)
   el.classList.add(className);
else
   el.className += ' ' + className;
```

Source: 
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#add_class

Comment: how would i do this in a method… it must be done in the addClass method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addClass(selector, class) {
    els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].className += class;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
addClass('div', 'border1');
addClass('#someID', 'someclass');
addClass('.someClass', 'someotherclass');
```

Comment: when i do add class it has to be in the exact format, as i would do it in jquery, so your way isn't really working!… :(

Comment: If you want to do it like jQuery, you have to define a class. That's more complicated than I feel like getting here.

Comment: Why does it HAVE to be the same format? Are you trying to replace jQuery without actually rewriting the code that uses it?

Comment: yes thats the exact description of the assignment. Part c) Add a New Method: addClass('newclass')
"
Add a new method which will add the given CSS class to each element that matches the selector. For example: $('div').addClass('foo'); should add the CSS class 'foo' to every <div> element on the page, as if they were declared as <div class="foo"> "

Comment: It would be nice if the question had said this was an assignment, and the object was about learning how to write Javascript classes. But didn't the class teach this? If not, how were you expected to do the assignment?

Answer (score 0):

I write this not so much as a recommendation, but because you seem to want to create a method, rather than a function; presumably under the impression that one might be better. They're much the same, however, except extending the prototype to add a method can potentially cause trouble. However, if you must:

```
NodeList.prototype.addClass = function (cName) {
    // creates an Array from the NodeList, and iterates through:
    return [].forEach.call(this, function (elem) {
        // adds the passed-in class-name:
        elem.classList.add(cName);
    });
};
```

The above can be called with:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').addClass('newClassName');
```

Or:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div').addClass('newClassName');
```

Note that this uses features found in relatively modern browsers, though they could be replaced with a `for` loop (`forEach`) and string-concatenation with `className` property (`classList.add()`) if desired.