# rewriting a Jquery script to vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vanilla-forums

Im trying to rewrite a jquery script i like in vanilla javascript and its not going well 
here is the original:
jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 225) {
        $('.sticky-nav').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('.site-title').addClass('visible-title');
    }
    else {
        $('.sticky-nav').removeClass('fixed-header');
        $('.site-title').removeClass('visible-title');
    }
});
```

so far ive changed it to:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
 if (document.window.scrollTop == 225 || document.documentElement.scrollTop == 225) {
        $('.sticky-nav').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('.site-title').addClass('visible-title');
    }
    else {
        $('.sticky-nav').removeClass('fixed-header');
        $('.site-title').removeClass('visible-title');
    }
}
```

codepen:https://codepen.io/robot_head/pen/WKverK

I dont get what to do for the if statement, or how to rewrite the add and remove class lines. Some pointers here would be helpful

Comment: `document.querySelector('.sticky-nav').classList.add()` in case you know it is only one element that matches. Otherwise use `document.querySelectorAll` instead, but be aware that the result is a `NodeList` (which you must iterate manually).

Comment: any suggestions on the if statement? the jquery one works the javascript one does not

Comment: `window.scrollY` I assume is what you need here. I don't know what the jQuery one does. Is that checking how far the user has scrolled from the top/start of the page?

Comment: Please do not edit the answers into your question. That makes it almost impossible to follow for future readers - please be aware that Stackoverflow is mainly a site where you can find answers to your questions without asking - because others have asked a similar question and you can find the answer using a search engine of your choice.

Comment: Asking to rewrite a whole script is off topic because it's too broad. Questions should be focused, how to implement scrollTop cross-browsers and how to add/remove class cross-browsers. If you search for those, you'll se they already exist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106827/scroll-eevent-and-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695272/how-would-i-write-this-jquery-addclass-method-in-vanilla-js

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, why haven't you picked an answer yet? If not, why haven't you commented accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`document.querySelector('.sticky-nav').classList.add()`

and

`document.querySelector('.sticky-nav').classList.remove()`

in case you know it is only one element that matches (or if the first match is the one you want).

Otherwise use `document.querySelectorAll` instead, but be aware that the result is a `NodeList` (even if it finds only one element), which you must iterate manually, e.g.

```
let navitems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');
for (let i = 0; i < navitems.length; i++) {
  navitem[i].classList.add('processed');
}
```